# Consistent, rhythmic water whooshing

Tags: plumbing, water

I have a consistent rhythmic whooshing sound in my water system when water is running. It sounds almost like a pump is causing it from a water supply pump house.

We live in the city and not far away from a pump house. Copper pipes. I have a small water hammer arrestor that looks like a straight pipe and is about one foot long. I have a hot water recirculation pump that circulates the hot water through a loop in the whole house. I have a water powered backup sump pump. The main line coming into the basement has a regulator on it.

I have turned valves off to all these one at a time but it doesn't stop the noise, it just changes it somewhat.

The whooshing is rhythmic at a rate of about 3 per second.

Any ideas on troubleshooting and stopping this? My concern is that pipe will eventually wear a small hole where they are clamped or touching something else.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is an answer or not but here goes.
I installed a pressure gauge. It was reading 65 psi when there was no water flowing. When water was flowing it was reading 35 - 37 and was fluctuating with the sound.

I messed with the regulator and brought the flowing pressure up to 50 psi. No more whooshing. Now my flowing pressure is 50 psi and non flowing pressure is 65 psi.

Comment: If that solved your problem, you should give it a check mark so folks can see that more easily.